# Fragment newinstance method if fragment is added through xml layout

Tags: android

As it's mentioned in various articles about using a static newInstance method for creating a fragment. I understand we can call this method if we create a fragment in code. But there is no way of getting this method called if fragment is added through xml layout file. In that case only constructor gets called. So what should be the approach in this case ?

Thanks

Dalvin

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but i think you are looking for this.

**Fragment f,and f1 are bulit in xml code , here we are initializing them by getting their Id's .**

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag1);

Fragment f1 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag2);

FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.detach(f);

        ft.commit();


        FragmentTransaction ft1=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft1.hide(f1);

    ft1.commit();
```

Comment: As newInstance() method is not the part of Fragment life cycle but a kind of design pattern introduced by android documentation. So if fragment is added through xml layout then this newInstance() method will not be called as we have to call this in code while creating fragment through code. So my question is how to adhere to this design pattern if i need to add fragment through xml layout.